# Android: how to use SectionIndexer

Tags: android, listview, header, indexer

I am trying to find a way to use `SectionIndexer`, instead of `AlphabetIndexer`. What I am interested to do is to have elements of a string arrays on the section headers instead of alphabets. I have not been able to find any sample code using section indexer.

Here is a sample code for `AlphabetIndexer`:

```
private AlphabetIndexer indexer;
indexer = new AlphabetIndexer(c, c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(
   DbHelper.COUNTRIES_NAME),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

Is it possible to pass a `stringArray` instead of "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" to the `AlphabetIndexer` so I can for example instead of "A", "B", ..."Z" as header have "Book", "Food", ...on the headers?

If not what is the best way to do that? Any reference to a sample code that uses `SectionIndexer` instead of `AlphabetIndexer` would be helpful as well.

Thanks for the help.
TJ

Comment: Are you just trying to separate elements in your ListView or is there another reason you want to use a SectionIndexer?

Comment: I want to create sections in my Listview,  each section with its own header and each section has a number of clickable elements. Of course section headers should not be clickable.

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224233/alphabetindexer-with-custom-adapter-managed-by-loadermanager

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try to write a custom `ArrayAdapter` and basically return a "section header" view in the `getView(...)` method for the positions where headers should appear.

You'll also have to overwrite `getViewTypeCount ()` to return the number of new types of views (in this case 2) and `getItemViewType (int position)` to return the type of view for the current position.

Also, the `onItemClickListener` should check to see if the item you clicked on is a section header.

This is my custom array adapter:

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModelItem>
{
    private static final int    TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int    TYPE_LIST_ITEM  = 1;

    int mDefaultRowLayoutResID;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ArrayList<ModelItem> lItems;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<ModelItem> items)
    {
        super(context, resource, items);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        lItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ModelItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return lItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return lItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        ModelItem item = lItems.get(position);
        if (item.isHeader())
        {
            return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
        }
        else
        {
            return TYPE_LIST_ITEM;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        ModelItem item = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            if (item.isHeader())
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_section_header, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title);
                holder.subtitle = null;
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_default, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_title);
                holder.subtitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_item_subtitle);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
        if (holder.subtitle != null)
        {
            holder.subtitle.setText(item.getSubtitle());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView subtitle;
        public ImageView leftIcon;
        public View rightControl;
    }
}
```

This is the row_item_default.xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/row_item_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row_item_title"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the row_item_section_header.xml:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_header_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
/>
```

The ModelItem class is a simple container for title, subtitle and a boolean to tell if it's a section header or not.

This is not the only way to write this adapter but I hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to use these codes and I have some questions before I can accept the answer. @Mircea thanks again for the help: In my previouse code I had an String Arrat "files" and the way I used it was: 'setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, files));' . Now using your code I should use ItemListAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter? What is the proper way of using it? Shall I have: 'setListAdapter(new ItemListAdapter <String>(this, R.layout.row, files));' ?

Comment: You could use it like

`setListAdapter(new ItemListAdapter <ModelItem>(this, R.layout.row, modelItems));`

But you must first build `ArrayList<ModelItem> modelItems` from your array of `files` and insert additional items where your section headers should be.

The idea is that your ItemListAdapter know where to inflate the row as a section header and where to inflate it as a normal row.
I did that by creating the ModelItem class and making it respond with true to isHeader() where the section headers should be and false for normal rows.