# Add String to adapter

Tags: android, arrays, list, adapter

I have an adapter and i want to add a string to it but when i run this code it only add the last string in the songstoadd variable ... That is a custom adapter which adds dividers in where neccessary but in the Array Adapter i want to a all of the strings that have the same first letter in their name ....

```
SeparatedListAdapter adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);
     ArrayList<String> songstoadd = new ArrayList<String>();

              Collections.sort(songtitle);
              int m = 0;
              while( m <songtitle.size()-1){
                  if(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1) == songtitle.get(m+1).substring(0, 1)){
                      m++;
                  }else{
                   songstoadd.clear();
                   songstoadd.add(songtitle.get(m));

                adapter.addSection(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1), new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songstoadd));

              m++;
                  }



      }
              setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

Comment: i think you need to convert Arraylist to String[] array

Comment: Look at my edited answer. visit the links..

Answer (score 1):

Try this, And let me know what happen..

```
songstoadd.clear();
 while( m <songtitle.size()-1){
                  if(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1).equals( songtitle.get(m+1).substring(0, 1))){
                      m++;
                  }else{

                songstoadd.add(songtitle.get(m));
                adapter.addSection(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1), new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songstoadd));

              m++;
                  }
```

For more info look at

[Android: how to use SectionIndexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861339/android-how-to-use-sectionindexer)

[Using AlphabetIndexer for fastscrolling ListView](http://www.anddev.org/tutusing_alphabetindexer_for_fastscrolling_listview-t10282.html)

[Create easy alphabetical scrolling in ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122749/create-easy-alphabetical-scrolling-in-listview)

Comment: It still adds every single song title to every section

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your while as below and try..

```
while(m <songtitle.size()-1){
     if(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1) == songtitle.get(m+1).substring(0, 1)){
         songstoadd.add(songtitle.get(m));
         m++;
     }else{

         songstoadd.add(songtitle.get(m));

         adapter.addSection(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1), new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songstoadd));

         songstoadd.clear();

         m++;
    }
}
```

Comment: THis only adds the Section Header and not anything from the songtitle array