# how to create sectionised listview like instagram in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have searched a lot to make sections in a `ListView` which will be exactly like Instagram

```
Edit profile      edit
Find Friend       search
------------------------------
Friend Request
------------------------------

kumar             accept
sheila            accept
------------------------------
------------------------------
```

I have something like the below examples:

[Example 1](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/)

[Example 2](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=992)

I haven't found exactly what I want. I have been through many blogs and the GitHub repository, but up until now I haven't gotten the exact method.  I would really be thankful if anybody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about SectionIndexer.

This could be helpful:

[Android: how to use SectionIndexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861339/android-how-to-use-sectionindexer)

http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Comment: its almost same..i need to know how to create that

Comment: thanks i have seen that but that's not the exact one..could you add some other answer

Comment: There won't always be a tutorial for exactly what you need. You need to find similiar tutorials and adapt them to your project.